# CSS translateY to animate slide down behind a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use transformY to animate the sliding down of an element when you click on a link in the header. The issue i'm having is that the element being displayed is nested a few levels deep and this is what I think is causing the problem - I need the element to slide down from behind the parent elements. Setting z-index doesn't appear to work in this context. I've created a JS Fiddle below - grateful for any help! In this demo, the green parent container should be sitting on top of the yellow hidden element.

```js
jQuery('.test-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('.container').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.outer-container {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}

.container .hidden-content {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.test-link {
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.container.active .hidden-content {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
 
.other-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  background: blue;
}

.test-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="test-content">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="test-link">TEST LINK</a>
      <div class="hidden-content">
        <h1>My Hidden Content</h1>
        <h1>My Hidden Content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="other-content">
 <h2>This should be overlaid by the sliding out content</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a negative `z-index`

```js
jQuery('.test-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('.container').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.another-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.outer-container {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container .hidden-content {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
}

.test-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.container.active .hidden-content {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="another-container">
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="test-content">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="test-link">TEST LINK</a>
      <div class="hidden-content">
        <h1>My Hidden Content</h1>
        <h1>My Hidden Content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>yellow box should be on top</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - the issue with using -1 z-index is then that the content will sit underneath other elements on the page once it slides out. In retrospect, my example was probably too simplistic.

Comment: @tomphilps not necessarily. You could introduce another wrapper around all of this stuff that you want the thing to slide underneath, and give that wrapper a positive z-index, so that it is on top of any content that comes after it. Updated my answer with an example since that's difficult to explain :)

Comment: I'm with you, though (again my simplistic example doesn't convey this well) adding position relative to a parent container then has a knock on effect in that my 100vw wide hidden element is being offset from the now relative parent. I'll update the code snippet to show this properly.